# Sencha Touch form panel, does not scroll with mouse

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a very long form, so the user needs to scroll down the form. When mouse is used to scroll, the form scroll down temporarily, but as soon the mouse is released the form again scrolls up. It works fine when using tab. 
Update - I have tried it on iPhone & Android device too, the same issue persists.

Here is my form panel :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Register', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'registerpage',
id: 'createPatientForm',


config: {
    title: 'Registration',
    iconCls: 'star',
    scroll: 'vertical',
    pinHeaders: true,
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    layout:{
        type: 'vbox'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        title: 'Registration',
        align: 'center',
        centered: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            label: 'First Name',
            name: 'firstName'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            label: 'Last Name',
            name: 'lastName'
        }
                    //many more items in the form.........
              ]

        }]
    }]
}
```

});

Comment: Sencha **Touch** is not supposed to be used by mouse-wielding devices...

Comment: I guess, as the mouse does not work, the same issue will arise when trying to scroll using the touch interface.

Comment: Could you please create a JSFiddle? It will make it easier for others trying to debug this problem. Might also help if you specify the ST2 version you are using, and the platform, browser etc you are testing on/in. Thanks.

Comment: here is the form - http://bit.ly/HgtNqW

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch 1 and 2 does not support the normal mouse scroll wheel. You must tap and drag on all devices.

**Update**

You do not need `autoScroll` in your configuration. You also need to take out the `layout: 'vbox'` as it is not needed. If you do those two things, it should just work.

Comment: I have tried on iPhone & Android device, the same issue persists there too, the form cannot be scrolled.

Comment: @Gaurav your `fieldset` has a `centered` config of `true`. This means it is centered within its container, and is floating. This will not allow the container to get its full height, therefor not allow you to scroll. If you remove this config it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Sencha Touch 2 remove **autoScroll** and change **scroll** to

```
scrollable: {
    direction: 'vertical',
    directionLock: true
}
```

Sencha Touch 2 API http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Panel-cfg-scrollable

Comment: Correct, though Ext.form.Panel's are scrollable by default, so he shouldn't need to do that. He just needs to remove the `layout` config.

Comment: You can see the live preview, it does not work  - http://maalguru.in/touch/Raxa/src/registration/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
Ext.define('overrides.SizeMonitor', {
 override: 'Ext.util.SizeMonitor',
 constructor: function (config) {
  var namespace = Ext.util.sizemonitor;
  return new namespace.Scroll(config);
 }
});

Ext.define('overrides.SizeMonitor', {
 override: 'Ext.util.PaintMonitor',
 constructor: function (config) {
  return new Ext.util.paintmonitor.CssAnimation(config);
 }
});
```